# where to store my PDF files for android bundle

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want to use and display PDF files in my app but I don't know how to include them in my android app bundle for the google store.
And what path to writing in order to send them to a PDF reader with an Intent.

Should I keep them in the Assets folder? If so what path to writing to the PDF reader?

Comment: if you don't want to include your pdf in-app bundle, show from the server

Comment: Asset manager returns a stream, so have your reader read the stream.

Comment: Can someone please show me a code example of how to take the stream from the assets folder and read it into a PDF reader. I am not completely clear about the code. I have seen code of how to use the reader but not on how to connect it to an asset file.